# Windows environment variable issue

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have two environment variables defined as:

```
test1=C:\something\dir1
test2=C:\something\dir2
```

And I'm trying to run the following command:

```
copy dir1\filename.txt dir2\filename.txt
```

I know that if I write the copy command with the environment variables it will work, like below:

```
copy %test1%\filename.txt %test2%\filename.txt
```

But isn't there a better way to do this? If Windows doesn't find the "dir1" directory in its current directory, won't it try to find it with the system variables it has?

EDIT: Im trying to use the copy command without typing the enviroment variable's name in the command.

Something like "copy dir1\filename.txt dir2\filename.txt", where, if Windows cant find the dir1 directory in its current directory, it would automatically search this directory with the enviroment variables. Is this possible?

Comment: No, you need to specify the path to the directory. Cmd will not check through every environment variable to see if any number of them have a word as a directory. Just specify the whole path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy the fully qualified path and filename, and cater for spaces etc.

```
copy "%test1%\filename.txt" "%test2%\"
```

If it doesn't work for you then edit your question and give more details about the task.

Comment: As unclemeat said, cmd wont check every enviroment variable, so I'll use this solution to make my code smaller.